# Bootstrap typeahead not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to use the Bootstrap typeahead - but have no luck getting it to work. I have tried both using `data-source` as well as manually with Javascript. My latest example is:

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
          $('.typeahead').typeahead({
             items:4,
             source: ['Aaaa', 'Abbb', 'Accc']
          });
     });
</script>
```

I am using jQuery 1.7.2... and yes, the jquery is propery loaded as I have other plugins that use jQuery and they all work properly. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you got any error in firebug or chrome devtools?

Comment: I have no errors - which is the difficult part. Neither in firebug or chrome dev

Comment: Also, the bootstrap is getting loaded - i verified with a few stop points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out. It was a CSS problem. I had customized my CSS download (I only want the typeahead) and left out other items I needed - IE, the typeahead uses a dropdown box. I didn't include that to begin with.